# Why it gives me "segmentation fault" error when I change this code?

Tags: c++, error-handling, segmentation-fault

I can compile this code without any errors:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <espeak/speak_lib.h>



espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
char *path=NULL;
int Buflength = 500, Options=0;
void* user_data;
t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
espeak_PARAMETER Parm;



char Voice[] = {"English"};


char text[30] = {"this is a english test"};
unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;




int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;
    int I, Run = 1, L;    
    espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, Options ); 
    espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
    const char *langNativeString = "en"; //Default to US English
    espeak_VOICE voice;
    memset(&voice, 0, sizeof(espeak_VOICE)); // Zero out the voice first
    voice.languages = langNativeString;
    voice.name = "US";
    voice.variant = 2;
    voice.gender = 1;
//  espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(&voice);
    Size = strlen(text)+1;    

    espeak_Synth( text, Size, position, position_type, end_position, flags,
    unique_identifier, user_data );
    espeak_Synchronize( );

    return 0;
}
```

But I get `segmentation fault` error when try to compile this code(putting all the code inside `man()`:

```
   #include <string.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <espeak/speak_lib.h>

    int main(){
    espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
    espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
    char *path=NULL;
    int Buflength = 500, Options=0;
    void* user_data;
    t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
    espeak_PARAMETER Parm;
    char Voice[] = {"English"};
    unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;

        output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;
        int I, Run = 1, L;    
        espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, Options ); 
        espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
        const char *langNativeString = "en"; //Default to US English
        espeak_VOICE voice;
            memset(&voice, 0, sizeof(espeak_VOICE)); // Zero out the voice first
            voice.languages = langNativeString;
            voice.name = "US";
            voice.variant = 2;
            voice.gender = 1;
            //espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(&voice);

        char tx[]="hi there, my name is Eliyaas, what's your name?";
        espeak_Synth( tx, strlen(tx)+1, position, position_type, end_position, flags,unique_identifier, user_data );
        espeak_Synchronize( );



    return 0;}
```

What is the difference and which line causes this error?
Is it possible to put all of this program inside `main()` function? How?

> (Add more text to pass add more information needed to post error) (Add
>   more text to pass add more information needed to post error) (Add more
>   text to pass add more information needed to post error) (Add more text
>   to pass add more information needed to post error)

Comment: Figure out how to run your program under a debugger. It should stop at the line that causes the crash and you should be able to look into variables to see the state of your program.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Hi , if you read this line of my question `(putting all the code inside man()` the only difference is putting the out of main codes inside the main. just this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are zero initialized in C++, local variables are not and it is Undefined Behavior to read from them. You have plenty of them in your code, for example:

```
espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
```

you need to edit your code and make sure that all variables are properly initialized. For example with `memset` if they are POD, the same way as it is done to `voice`.

Comment: Can I initialize all of them to zero like these `espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type=0;` or `espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output=0;`

Comment: I am not familiar with that library, but looks like they are structures not simple types, if this is the case then no.

Comment: So, if they are structures, I must set all their variable to zero one-by-one?

Comment: @user145959 `espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output = {0};` will 0 the whole struct.

Comment: @UKMonkey: should I initialize *pointers to 0 too? for example `    void* user_data=0;`

Comment: @user145959 the thing about initializing variables, is that it's something that you don't NEED to do at all as a rule of thumb.  The problem is that if you dont' do it, you may be tempted to use it before it has a value; which leads to undefined behavior.  If you want to ensure that you never, ever use a variable uninitialised (a wise plan), then you should initialise everything; classes being an exception; as they have a constructor so can ensure that they themselves are correctly initialised

Comment: @UKMonkey:  `app3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
app3.cpp:7:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT’ [-fpermissive]
 espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output={0};`

Comment: Also `app3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
app3.cpp:6:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘espeak_POSITION_TYPE’ [-fpermissive]
 espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type=0;
                                    ^
app3.cpp:7:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT’ [-fpermissive]
 espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output=0;`

Comment: @user145959 looks like this is a C lib, and in their example they use `memset` already. Probably it would be easiest to initialize rest of them the same way. I already mentioned that in my answer.